# converting time formats from SAS to sql (converting time elapsed to date)

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, timestamp, sas

I have a dataset that appears to have time in an "elapsed" format (possibly in SAS format, where time is expressed as number of seconds elapsed since Jan 1st 1960).  In a sql query I would like to convert this to a timestamp or date format.  Is there a nice, clean way to do this?

Something similar to the answer here, except I need it in psql, not Python:
[Time and date on the basis of seconds elapsed since 1970 year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778460/time-and-date-on-the-basis-of-seconds-elapsed-since-1970-year)

Here is a sample of my data:

```
time_var      
-------------
1344444527000  
1344448596000  
1344455497000  
1344445125000
```

Here is the type of query I'd like to make:

```
select
   time_var
   cast(time_var as timestamp) as mytimestamp,
   cast(time_var as date)      as mydatetime, 
   date(time_var)              as mydate 
from
   source_dataset
;
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: ... Since 1960?  Most RDBMSs should allow something along the lines of `CAST('1960-01-01' as TIMESTAMP) + 1 seconds`.  Might have specific functions to add date/time intervals, though.

Comment: I'm using postgres.  I can get an interval FROM a date, but not a date from an interval.  I'm attempting stuff line `(date '1960-01-01' + interval cast(time_var as varchar)) as temp_output`

Comment: Those are not SAS DATETIME values.  If you remove the last three zeros, they are.  The value `1344444527` is equal to `08AUG2002:16:48:47` in SAS.  Any idea what they should be?

Comment: In general, I can't seem to run interval on a text variable.  I made a query to put my time_var into a string using this: `(cast(time_var as varchar) || ' seconds') as temp_interval`, but then I can't seem to run this in a later query on that temp table: `(date '1960-01-01' + interval temp_interval) as temp_output`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my dataset is using UNIX timestamps, so the values are big integers (the extra zeros need to be stripped) and the time is from Jan 1st 1970.  I obtained the following code from my boss to convert these:

```
select
   timestamp with time zone 'epoch' + interval '1 second' *
      cast((cast(time_var as bigint) / 1000) as integer) as postgres_timestamp,
   date(timestamp with time zone 'epoch' + interval '1 second' *
      cast((cast(time_var as bigint) / 1000) as integer)) as postgres_date
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Oracle example that may help you. There are some assumptions and I removed 0-s from your number. I hope you find this useful whatever database you are using:

```
SELECT total_days
     , CAST(end_date AS timestamp) t_stamp
     , CAST(end_date AS date) final_date_time
     -- date(end_date) will not work as end_date is date already
     , TO_CHAR(TRUNC(end_date), 'MM/DD/YYYY') final_date
  FROM
  (
   SELECT ROUND(1344444527/60/60/24)         total_days
        , TO_DATE('01-01-1960','dd-mm-yyyy') start_date
        , TO_DATE('01-01-1960','dd-mm-yyyy')+ (1344444527/60/60/24) end_date
     FROM dual
  )
  /

SQL>

 TOTAL_DAYS   T_STAMP                       FINAL_DATE_TIME       FINAL_DATE
 ----------   -------------------------     -------------------   ----------
 15561        8/8/2002 4:48:47.000000 PM    8/8/2002 4:48:47 PM   08/08/2002
```